# Android AES encryption with python AES encryption

Tags: java, python, encryption

I have created the following python code
    import base64

```
from django.conf import settings
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

BS = 16


def pad(s):
    return s + (BS - len(s) % BS) * chr(BS - len(s) % BS)

def unpad(s):
    return s[0:-s[-1]]

class AESCipher:
    def __init__(self):
         self.key = settings.SECRET_KEY

    def encrypt(self, raw):
        raw = pad(raw)
        iv = settings.SECRET_IV.encode('utf-8')
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        return base64.b64encode(cipher.encrypt(raw))

    def decrypt(self, enc):
        enc = base64.b64decode(enc)
        iv = settings.SECRET_IV.encode('utf-8')
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        return unpad(cipher.decrypt(enc))

    def encryptstring(self, raw):
        raw = self.encrypt(raw)
        raw = raw.decode('utf-8')
        return raw

    def decryptstring(self, raw):
        raw = raw.encode('utf-8')
        raw = self.decrypt(raw)
        raw = raw.decode('utf-8')
        return raw
```

This code returns a base64 encrypted string (i.e. `VgRaS+J3MSmguabaf+9fJw==`).

I have also created a java function, that should create the same thing, but it doesn't match.

```
    public void login() {
    SecretKeySpec keySpec;
    IvParameterSpec ivSpec;
    Cipher cipher;

    String key = "";
    String iv = "";

    try {
        keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
        ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes());
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");

        String test = "Test";
        String newString = "";
        char paddingChar = ' ';
        int size = 16;
        int x = test.length() % size;
        int padLength = size - x;
        for (int i = 0; i < padLength; i++) {
            newString += paddingChar;
//                test += paddingChar;
        }
        newString += test;

        byte[] res;

        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);
        res = cipher.doFinal(newString.getBytes());
        for(int i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(res[i] + ", ");
        }

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println(bytesToHex(res));
        String base = Base64.encodeToString(res, Base64.DEFAULT);
        System.out.println(base);

//          TODO: VgRaS+J3MSmguabaf+9fJw==
        //    OyuUHNsBQ3Zuy4UGY4fUdQ==
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The result I get there is `2mdRXydTCAYG+Tp0kE/NoQ==`. It looks similar, but it isn't. I have checked the keys, they are the same. I have swapped them around, to make sure that wasn't the problem either. I have tried different cipher modes (`AES/CBC/ISO10126Padding` and `AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding`) both without result. I have tried to do it with plain AES, no success either. I tried to get `AES_128/CBC/NoPadding` and `AES_256/CBC/NoPadding` to work, but for some reason it tells me `java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: No provider found for AES_256/CBC/NoPadding`.

I am lost, I hope someone can help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your Python code uses a fixed IV.  Fix that first.

Comment: I am aware. It is the way I want to use that. The android code uses the same IV, also fixed. Why would that matter?

Comment: Uhhh..  Using a fixed IV is a security vulnerability.  If you want vulnerable encryption code then be my guest.

Comment: Yes, I want a security vulnerability...

Comment: Then don't change it. ;) If you change your mind and decide you want secure encryption code, you should randomly generate the IV for each encryption operation.  It isn't a secret value, just needs to be random.

Comment: Alright. The issue remains though. Only changing the IV doesn't fix the problem. It's a problem somewhere else. Would you be able to help out with that by any chance?

Comment: You're using different padding.

Comment: @JamesKPolk in both instances I add emptyness. Is this wrong?

Comment: @JamesKPolk you are a genius. That's it! Thanks an awful lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As JamesKPolk pointed out, the padding was wrong. I have solved this by doing the following:

Python has the following

```
def pad(s):
    return s.ljust(16, '0')
```

Java has the following

```
char paddingChar = '0';
```